# “Is there an R function(text-analysis) for tagging the subject of word( eg : noun,adj)?”

Tags: r, nlp

I am doing a text-mining about sentiment analysis. However, i have met a problem when I was using text-mining with English articles. I want to ask is there any function similar to the function "worker(type='tag')" of Jieba package, but it is using in the English text-mining package (eg: tidytext)?

In the following, it is part of my code. This code is using for Chinese text-mining. However, i want to do a English text-mining by the similar way. What function can I use to replace the function  of worker(type="tag")

```
library(jiebaRD)
library(jiebaR)
library(dplyr)
jieba <- worker(type="tag",user="C:/Users/User/Desktop/dict/bbb.txt",symbol = TRUE)

ecal<-function(str){
  result <- jieba <= str    
  winfront <- 1L 
  count <- 1  
  winvalue <- c()  
  posvalue <- c()  
  negvalue <-c ()  
  pvalue <- 0L     
  nvalue <- 0L    
  ppcount <- 1
  nncount <- 1
  rheflag <- FALSE
  for (i in 1:length(result)){
    if(names(result[i])=="positive"){      
      #cat("find positive word：",result[i],"\n")      
      if(i==1)
        winvalue[count] <- 1
      else{
        winvalue[count] <- 1
        for (j in (i-1):winfront) {
          if(!is.na((as.numeric(names(result[j])))))
            winvalue[count] = winvalue[count]*as.numeric(names(result[j]))
          else if(names(result[j])=="deny")
            winvalue[count] = winvalue[count]*(-1)
          else if(names(result[j])=="rhe")
            rheflag <- TRUE
        }
      }
      #cat("the value of window is：",winvalue[count],"\n")      
      count = count+1
      winfront <- i+1
    }
```

Comment: [cleanNLP](https://github.com/statsmaths/cleanNLP) is a good jumping-off point for PoS tagging

Answer (score 0):

You could do as follows:

```
library(udpipe)
x <- udpipe("我拜訪了我在香港的朋友", "chinese")
```

Note that if you have already a tokenizer in chinese (e.g. Jieba), you can also use udpipe to enrich your tokenised data with pos tags - see section 'My text data is already tokenised' in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/udpipe/vignettes/udpipe-annotation.html#annotate_your_text

Accuracy stats on the model build on Chinese-GSD from universal dependencies are reported here: https://github.com/jwijffels/udpipe.models.ud.2.3/blob/master/inst/udpipe-ud-2.3-181115/README
Tokenisation is suboptimal but pos tagging given gold tokenisation is pretty fine regarding accuracy.